# How to access Principal in controller methods without it declared as argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I added Spring Security on a Rest API with JWT authentication. Now I need to retrieve some data from the token in every controller method - be it either the username or other information.

Since almost all of my controller methods would need a `Principal` variable, is there a way to avoid declaring it as an argument to each method?

I once used [`ObjectProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) to do a similar thing, like:

```
@RequestScope
@Component
public class MyObj // ...
```

Usage:

```
@Component
public class OtherObj {
    
    @Autowired
    private ObjectProvider<MyObj> provider;

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean meth() throws Exception {
        MyObj o = provider.getIfAvailable();
        
        // ...
```

But there I found that if no instance exists, it is created instead of being returned `null` or an exception being thrown.

Comment: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` will give you the principal

Answer (score 1):

You can create one utility class, which provides you the principal.

```
public static Principal getPrincipal() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    return securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

Ofcourse, here you would need to put the null checks in case the context or authentication is null.